Expected fn pointer, found closure, when i pass struct for the function
I created an impl to be able to manage some asynchronous functions that must be executed as soon as my app opens.
My problem is that when I pass a struct as a parameter, the compiler gives the following error:
note: expected fn pointer `fn() -> Pin<Box<(dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'static)>>`
                 found closure `{closure@src/main.rs:50:52: 50:54}`
note: closures can only be coerced to `fn` types if they do not capture any variables

I've already searched for 2 whole days and I can't find the solution, I made an example on the playground to make it easier to execute.
Playground Link
I've already looked for some answers here on StackOverflow and in other forums, all the answers I tested didn't work

Does this answer your question? Why does passing a closure to function which accepts a function pointer not work?

No, before my code was different, I found this question and changed my code to try the proposed solution, and it still doesn't work.

As stated in the compiler diagnostic error message, your Service::new takes an function pointer as argument (i.e., fn ()).
You are instead passing a closure.
A closure is not a function pointer. A closure may decay (be implicitly converted) into a function pointer, but it is not always the case.
See the compiler note:

note: closures can only be coerced to fn types if they do not capture any variables

In particular:
cron_orchestrator.add_new_service(Service::new(|| Box::pin(fun3(person)) ));

the closure is capturing a reference to person and that creates a closure with a state (it is more than a simple function, it is stateful).

A possibility is to use dynamic dispatching over trait Fn (which is trait which covers both function and closure).
A minimal example:
type Service<T> = Box<dyn Fn() -> ServiceResponse<T>>;

A Service here is a generic dynamic type (can be anything implementing Fn).
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=34960188f7f5d041067b452ad9a1b3aa

Bonus: as your CronOrchestrator::run does not "consume" the service you need Fn trait as the function might call more than once.
Maybe you could slightly modify your code with FnOnce is the service is called only once per application initialization.
